# Git pre-push hook hangs after piping to xclip

Tags: git, githooks, xclip

## Preamble:

When committing I tend to format message as following:

`[<task number>] <task title>`

which should be converted by pre-push hook to a valid GitHub syntax as following:

`Work item [[<git_branch>](http://tracker/_workitems/<git_branch>)]:`

`- [x] [[<task_number>](http://tracker/_workitems/<task_number>)] <task title>`

and then it's `cat`ted to console output so i can copy-paste it to PR description on github.

## Task

Go one step further and put that message into clipboard so that I don't have to manually select it and copy from console.
Since I'm on Linux machine I decided that I'll use `xclip` for the task.

My current git hook script looks as following:

```
#!/bin/sh

PBI=\`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD\`

echo "**Backlog Item [$PBI]:**\n" > pr_messages/$PBI.md

git log develop..HEAD --format=" - [x] %B" >> pr_messages/$PBI.md

sed -r -i 's|\[([0-9]{4,})\]|[[\1](http://tracker/_workitems/\1)]|g' pr_messages/$PBI.md

cat pr_messages/$PBI.md
```

## Problem

When I add following line to the end of this script

```
cat pr_messages/$PBI.md | xclip -selection clipboard
```

I get the message in my Ctrl+C/V clipboard, but git hangs and I have to abort it. Given that it's supposed to be a pre-push hook, it effectively prevents me from actually pushing my code.

**UPD:** As proposed by @wumpus-q-wumbley here's the strace output:

```
$> ps aux | grep git

kraplax  29796  0.0  0.0  25696  5660 pts/1    S+   12:55   0:00 git push
kraplax  29797  0.0  0.0  48276  3040 pts/1    S+   12:55   0:00 ssh git@github.com git-receive-pack 'eduard-sukharev/ProFIT.git'

$> sudo strace -p 29796
Process 29796 attached
wait4(29797, 
^CProcess 29796 detached
 <detached ...>
$> sudo strace -p 29797
Process 29797 attached
select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL
^CProcess 29797 detached
 <detached ...>
```

Which essentially shows that git-push is waiting for the ssh process `ssh git@github.com git-receive-pack 'eduard-sukharev/ProFIT.git'` which hangs. This all shifts the focus of the problem a bit.

**UPD2:** Setting `GIT_TRACE=~/git_trace.log` gives this info:

```
$ cat ../git_trace.log 
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--abbrev-ref' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--abbrev-ref' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain'
trace: built-in: git 'push'
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''eduard-sukharev/ProFIT.git'\'''
trace: run_command: '.git/hooks/pre-push' 'origin' 'git@github.com:eduard-sukharev/ProFIT.git'
trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '--short' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'log' 'develop..HEAD' '--format= - [x] %B'
trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--abbrev-ref' 'HEAD'
trace: built-in: git 'status' '--porcelain'
```

## Question

Why does this process hang if otherwise it doesn't?

How should I rewrite that line to complete intended task?

Should I probably use other tool for managing clipboard, other than `xclip`?

Comment: Did you ever try to run `cat pr_messages/$PBI.md | xclip -selection clipboard` alone? The pre-push-hook must return a `0` to continue working (if this would be the matter git should rather fail than hang up) properly - it may be that the xclip-command fails?

Comment: Oh and would you be that nice to tell which Git-version you're using?

Comment: @florianb yes, i did try running `cat pr_messages/$PBI.md | xclip -selection clipboard` in bash itself and it did work. Once it worked in bash alone i've just copy-pasted that command into the hook, hoping it will work, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: @florianb i can't tell you exactly, but let's assume that i use the most recent git version available in Kubuntu 14.04 LTS (which is 1.9.1 according to [this entry](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/git))

Comment: Getting the exact version is necessary to check the release-notes for potential bugs (but it seems that the hooks worked pretty well). Did you ever try to finish the line with an ampersand `&`? You might also try to append a new line containing an explicit `exit 0`.

Comment: @florianb i have tried adding ampersand and it didn't work either. Tomorrow i will try the 'exit 0' trick. Also then i could tell the exact version of git I use.

Comment: Thanks - for the case it doesn't work you could also determine the name of the process which hangs.

Comment: @florianb `exit 0` trick didn't work, but i've tried strace'ing the processes as proposed by @wumpus-q-wumbley and updated my question

Comment: Hmm - this problem is hard to pin down. As long as there is no solution you might try to [use `xsel` to to copy text into the clipboard](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility).

Comment: I can only guess what might go wrong. I would like to ask you to create a debug-log, by setting the environment-var [`GIT_TRACE`](http://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Debugging) to a path for the wished log-file and post its output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89570/discussion-between-eduard-sukharev-and-florianb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`xsel`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel), as well as [`xclip`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip), waits until another program explicitly fetches the selected data.

> This behavior is a design-conditional of X11, since there "is no X selection buffer. The selection mechanism in X11 is an interclient communication mediated by the X server each time any program wishes to know the selection contents [...]. In order to implement modification of the selection(s) (in input, keep and exchange modes) [these programs detach] from the terminal, spawning a child process to supply the new selection(s) on demand. This child exits immediately when any other program takes over the selection(s)" *-- from the xsel man-page*

With other words your Gits `pre-push` commit is executed until you start providing your text-selection to the clipboard. The process is then halted until you are making use of this text-snippet by invoking any command or executing any program which "fetches" the clipboard text.

#### Forking the `xclip`-command does not work

My first idea was to detach this selection-providing process to let it live parallel to the (then) ongoing execution of your hook-script. Unfortunately this does not work, either the main-process ist halting anyways, until the subprocess returns, or the text-selection of the forked command is not available to the current X11-server.

## Possible Solutions

Due to the behavior of the "clipboard" in X11 you must evade providing text-selections in the time-relevant processing of git-hooks.

1. **Use a clipboard-manager** - The most clipboard-managers (like [Klipper](https://userbase.kde.org/Klipper) [for KDE] or [Glipper](https://launchpad.net/glipper) [for Gnome]) provide mechanisms to decouple the supply of data from its usage - which emulates the clipboard behavior of Windows and Mac OS.
2. **Alias the `git-push`-command** - if you're operating your git-repository mostly in  the shell you might wrap the `git-push`-command in an alias or small shell-script which first invokes the push and afterwards provides the text-snippet to the clipboard. The disadvantage of this approach is, (besides of the cli-dependency) that the command will "hang" at the end, until you fetched the clipboard-content.

Unless you're not able to install additional software to your system i'd recommend the use of a clipboard-manager.

## Use Klipper to put Text from the CLI into the X11-clipboard

You can access Klipper through the shell by using [qdbus](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/qdbus.1.html) - a command-line-interface to Qt-applications. An example took from [Milian Wolff's Blog Post](http://milianw.de/code-snippets/access-klipper-clipboard-on-cli-under-kde4), adapted to your script, may look like the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

PBI=\`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD\`
echo "**Backlog Item [$PBI]:**\n" > pr_messages/$PBI.md
git log develop..HEAD --format=" - [x] %B" >> pr_messages/$PBI.md

sed -r -i 's|\[([0-9]{4,})\]|[[\1](http://tracker/_workitems/\1)]|g' pr_messages/$PBI.md

PR_MESSAGE=$(cat pr_messages/$PBI.md)
qdbus org.kde.klipper /klipper setClipboardContents "$PR_MESSAGE"
```

Another interesting article about the interaction of qdbus and Klipper: https://askubuntu.com/questions/393601/a-command-for-pasting-the-same-as-ctrl-v

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the xclip background process still has an open file descriptor on the original stdout of the script, preventing git from receiving an EOF on the pipe where it reads the output of the hook. Try adding `> /dev/null` to the xclip command.

Comment: In that case I have no more guesse. I'd investigate by looking at what processes are running when the command seems to be stuck, and `strace -p` them to see what they're waiting on.